# Передавать и принимать данные в формате JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Ребята ,есть определенный код который надо как-то подключить к базе данных и чтоб записывалось в формате JSON  но почему-то не выходит (Помогите пожалуйста . В том что делалось должно по первому нажатию записываться 1 и кнопка чтоб горела зеленым ,по второму нажатию записывается 0 и кнопка серым горит .

```
var result = 0;
var myEvent = function() {
  if (result == 0) {
    document.getElementById('my-button').style.backgroundColor = '#4cff00';
    result = 1;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('my-button').style.backgroundColor = '#6b7077';
    result = 0;
  }
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
{
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var n_JSON = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    var ID = n_JSON.ID;
    var result = n_JSON.result1;
} 
    if (ID == 1 && result == 0) 
{
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', "con_data_ajax/work-ajax-data.php?user-work="+user+,true); 
  let body = 'result=' + result;
  xhr.send(body);
  if (xhr.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
  } 
}
#my-button {
  background-color: #6b7077;
}
<button id="my-button" onclick="myEvent()">в работе</button>
<div id="result">0</div>
```

вот что на аяксе но оно не работает ( НЕ СУДИТЕ СТРОГО , Я В ЭТОМ НОВЕНЬКИЙ .

Я хотел передать такой смысл : у каждого пользователеля есть свой ID  под которым он заходит на страничку и там уже нажимает на кнопку которая привязана к этому ID  и при нажатии записывается 1 и кнопка горит еще раз повторюсь "зеленой" ,второй раз нажимаю и уже "серая"

```
$answer = '{"ID":"0", "Name":"xxx"}';

if(($_POST['login']=="tech_user") AND ($_POST['pass']=="111")){

    $answer = '{"ID":"1", "Name":"Копыча"}';

}
if (($_POST['ID']=="1")) {
$answer = '{"result":"1"}' ;
OR
$answer = '{"result":"0"}' ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятна логика как оно должно работать. Из того что понял, получилось что-то типа такого: https://codepen.io/Lukyanenko/pen/QBNzjX?editors=1111

```
var button = document.getElementById('my-button');

button.addEventListener( "click" , function(ev){
  if (ev.target.dataset.userId === '1'){
    this.style.backgroundColor = '#4cff00'
 //Получаем данные по юзеру
 var userId = ev.target.dataset.userId;
 var userName = ev.target.dataset.userName;
  // формируем тело на отправку
 var json = JSON.stringify({
  id: userId,
  surname: userName
});
  //Формируете запрос согласно того как у вас настроен сервер.
// var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
// xhr.open(.....)
// xhr.send(json)
}else {
  this.style.backgroundColor = '#6b7077'
}
ev.target.dataset.userId = 0;
});
```

Comment: Немного не то , кнопка по идее должна переключаться постоянно с серого на зеленый и с зеленого на серый + самое главное я не знаю как подключиться к аяксу . Как к нему подключиться  чтоб здесь все записывалось  "ID":"1"   '{"result":"1"}'

Comment: В jquery  есть хороший метод - $ajax. Посмотри, может тебе подойдет.

Comment: в том то  и дело что мне нужно без Jquery  это сделать ,есть вариантик ?

Comment: А что не получается с XMLHttpRequest ? Ошибку получаешь или в чем именно проблема? Тебе надо собрать тело и отправить его на сервер.

Comment: Я просто не понимаю как в моем случае прописывать пусть здесь xhr.open ( ) если например есть сам файл connect.php  и в нем аякс          
 if (($_POST['ID']=="1")) {
$answer = '{"result":"1"}' ;
OR
$answer = '{"result":"0"}' ;
}

Comment: сам путь мне кажется не правильно прописан здесь xmlhttp.open("GET" $_GET['result']"connect.php?my-button="+button+,true);   my-button это сама кнопка ,connect.php - куда данные передаются  ,button  это переменная

Comment: что здесь не так то ?

Comment: Как я понял сервер ожидает POST, а вы передаете GET. xhr.open('POST', '/submit', true); - так тоже не работает?

Comment: Нет ,там везде ГЕТ запрос ,ошибся просто  но здесь что-то не так ...xmlhttp.open("GET" $_GET['result']"connect.php?my-button="+button+,true);  Вроде бы по логике все правильно

Comment: может здесь скобки не нужны или с ковычками что-то не так ...не пойму ((